# Link Dynamic SQL Chart In Powerpoint

Tags: sql, excel, powerpoint

I'm working on a project that needs to be displayed via Powerpoint. I have a SQL chart that is refreshed every morning at 9 am and 12 pm with updated results. I need this information to display within a Powerpoint slideshow for our team, but I'm not sure how to do this where I can see the updated results. I tried inserting the excel spreadsheet as an object and linking that way, but that has not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the chart is in Excel and automatically refreshes, try it like so:

First, make sure that the PPT file and the XL file are in the same folder if possible.

Select the chart in Excel and rightclick/copy.

Switch to PowerPoint.

Use Paste Special and put a check next to Link to paste the chart into PPT.
I would paste it onto a slide that does NOT have a content placeholder; delete it or put some text into it if one's already there, then paste the chart.

PowerPoint should now update the chart each time you open the presentation, assuming the data/chart have changed in XL.